# How to get pixels coordinates from binary image?

Tags: image, binary, coordinates, pixel

How to get all black pixels coordinates from binary image (white and black picture)?
I want to get readable coordinates like: 1x 1y; 50x 60y; and so on...
What tool should I use?

Comment: You can use imtool command to show  the coordinates

Comment: Is the image already rasterized? If so, you could simply use a control structure of two for loops for the x and y rows and columns respectively.